# No errors with express-validator isEmpty

Tags: express, express-validator

I am using express-validator 5.2.0 in a expressjs app. I implemented the validaiton on a form data. But it does not capture the errors and gives empty errors object. When validation runs it shows the "no error" when I submit the empty form. It should follow the error path and should display the error.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

router.post('/register', [
  check('firstName', 'First Name is required').isEmpty(),
  check('lastName', 'Last Name is required').isEmpty(),
  check('username', 'User Name is required').isEmpty(),
  check('password', 'Password is required').isEmpty()
], (req, res, next)=>{
  let errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors.mapped());
    console.log("errors")
    return res.render('auth/register', { errors: errors.mapped() })
  }else{
    console.log('no errors')
    return res.render('auth/login');
  }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`check('firstName', 'First Name is required').isEmpty()` **is enforcing `firstName` to be empty.**
You will want to change that last part to `.not().isEmpty()`, so that you invert the `isEmpty` validator.

<sub>Might also be of your interest: https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/476</sub>

Comment: If I chain like: .not().isEmpty().isAlphanumeric() ... Will it revert the isAlphanumeric() part of the chain... or it reaches only the next instance of the chain?

Comment: @bugthefifth No. According to the docs, it only "Negates the result of the next validator.

"

Answer (score 9):

In your snippet you have not added a validtor to check if a value is **not empty**.
You could achieve this by doing:

```
check('firstName', 'First Name is required').notEmpty()
```

**.notEmpty()** adds a validator to check if a value is not empty; that is, a string with a length of 1 or bigger.

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#notempty